# Initialize entry in Java Map with single look up (like in C++)

Tags: java, collections

In C++, I can look up a key in a map and insert it if it's not there for the cost of a single look up. Can I do the same in Java?

**Update**:

(For those of you who must see code.)

```
long id = 0xabba;
int version = 0xb00b;  
for (List<Object> key : keys) {
    if (!index.containsKey(key)) {
      index.put(key, Maps.<Long,Integer>newHashMap());
    }
    index.get(key).put(id, version);
}
```

There are two look ups when the key is first inserted into the map. In C++, I could do it with a single look up.

Comment: What value would be inserted if the key is not present?

Comment: Please provide some sample code - not sure what you really mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Concurrent maps have an atomic [`putIfAbsent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#putIfAbsent%28K,%20V%29) method, if this is what you mean.

Comment: +1; was not aware of that feature. seems to be what OP is looking for!

Comment: How does the performance of such a map compare to an ordinary map with a combined find+insert?

Comment: @Kerrek, `ConcurrentHashMap`, as it is not using any locking for reads, is actually comparable to the standard HashMap in single-threaded performance (and way faster than `Hashtable` on any number of threads). `ConcurrentSkipListMap` is slightly slower. The `size` method of each of these is not constant time though.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely familiar with C++ intrinsic implementation, but I have some doubts about it being a single operation in terms of performance/efficiency.

Even if it was, why would you necessarily need one in Java? Or even want one?

Assuming that it looks something like:

`lookup(object) // side effect of object insertion`

I wouldn't want something like this in Java for anything other than concurrency.

EDIT: clarification